# Duplicates when iterating loop in jade

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, pug

I have an array, globally defined in my Node.js app index, app.js like

```
posts = [];
```

this array is filled with blocks of html, and if I loop the array in my index, I get the following (currently only filled with one block)

```
for(var i in posts) console.log(posts[i]);

<h1 id="this-is-ma-title">this is ma title</h1>
<p>hello <strong>123</strong></p>
```

this is the expected result. When I try to print out this array in the view model however, like this

```
extends layout
block content
  .post
    #{posts}
```

the content seems to duplicate, and also contains random < > notation in the client browser

```
<div class="post"><<h1 id="this-is-ma-title">this is ma title</h1>
<p>hello <strong>123</strong></p>
></<h1 id="this-is-ma-title">this is ma title</h1>
<p>hello <strong>123</strong></p>
></div>
```

I have tried various differentiations of the loop notation, like

```
each item in posts
  item
```

and

```
- for (var i=0; i<posts.length; i++) {
.post
  #{posts[i]
- }
```

but all produce similar results.. am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue came with the fact the code buffered by `=` is escaped by default for security, however to output unescaped return values you can use `!=`

So a solution to this would be:

```
each item in posts
  p!= item
```