# Modal content duplicate

Tags: html, bootstrap-modal, pug

So the button works content works fine but until I click on the button it duplicates the first array content, I have tried using the solutions to the other answers on another stackoverflow post but they don't help me or work. Please help

```
each note in notes
  a(class='clickablebox', class='link', data-toggle='modal', data-target='#infoModal#{note.id}') #{note.title}
  div(class='modal fade', id='infoModal#{note.id}', tabindex='-1', role='dialog', aria-labelledby='infoModalLabel', aria-hidden='true')
    .modal-dialog.modal-dialog-centered(role='document', id='#{note.id}')
      .modal-content
        .modal-header
          h5#infoModalTitle.modal-title #{note.title}
          button.close(type='button' data-dismiss='modal' aria-label='Close') 
            i(class='fa fa-times')     
        .modal-body
          | #{note.content}
```

Notes is `[{'id': 'e', title: 'a', content: 'content'}, {'id': 'a', title: 'e', content: 'content'}]]`

Tried:
[Duplicates when iterating loop in jade](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35712500/duplicates-when-iterating-loop-in-jade)
[Insert dynamic data into bootstrap modal from array object - vanilla javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70053023/insert-dynamic-data-into-bootstrap-modal-from-array-object-vanilla-javascript)

And others that should to add an id to each modal

Comment: I recommend adding what troubleshooting steps you tried from other Stack Overflow posts so that when people try to help you they do not duplicate answers or link you to the posts you already tried.

Comment: Note, this code will cause you to have multiple identical `id` attributes in the same document, which is invalid HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so it seemed like 'infoModal#{note.id}' so I just had to do 'infoModal'+note.id